# Como listar archivos de una carpeta donde esta un archivo concreto con python

Tags: python

Me gustaría saber como puedo con pyhton listar todos los archivos de una carpeta que contenga un archivo en concreto de tal manera que si ese archivo lo muevo a otra carpeta me liste los archivos de la nueva carpeta donde esta ubicado.
Gracias!

Comment: Hola, bienvenida  a SOes, ¿podrías dar un ejemplo de lo que quieres lograr?

Comment: Hola!!! Pues por ejemplo, si yo tengo mi archivo "prueba.txt" en cualquier carpeta dentro de C:\\ y la muevo a una carpeta dentro de D:\\ que python me devuelva una lista de todos los archivos que hay en esa carpeta de C:\\ o de D:\\

Comment: Échale un ojo a las librerías `os.path`, `pathlib`, `glob` y/o `shutil`, todas de la stdlib

Comment: Entiendo que lo que quieres son dos cosas: 1) buscar el directorio donde está un fichero, 2) Listar todos los ficheros de ese directorio

Answer (score 1):

```
import os

scanned = 0

infected = "prueba.txt" 

#Busca en todas los directorios de "C:/" el archivo "prueba.txt"
y cuando lo encuentra hace un print del directorio del archivo
for root, dirs, files in os.walk('C:/'):
    scanned = scanned + 1
    for file in files:
        if infected in file:
            print((root + "/" + file))
            print("Archivos total escaneados: " + str(scanned))
```

Comment: Sería ideal si pudieras incluir una descripción de lo que hace este código.